# Will a Treemap resort if a TreeMap passed to it as Map

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap

We define a new TreeMap in a method and pass it to another method:

```
TreeMap aTreeMap = new TreeMap();
//call another method to doSomething with map
doSomeThing(aTreeMap)
```

The `doSomething()` is as below:

```
 doSomething(Map aMap){  
    //Make a new copy of
    TreeMap aTreeMap = new TreeMap(aMap);    
}
```

Will the new TreeMap resort the data?!

Comment: Why don't you check it by your self ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the implementation of `TreeMap` on [grepcode.com](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/TreeMap.java#TreeMap.%3Cinit%3E%28java.util.SortedMap%29), 
it has these constructors (among others):

```
public TreeMap(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> m) {
    comparator = null;
    putAll(m);
}

public TreeMap(SortedMap<K, ? extends V> m) {
    comparator = m.comparator();
    try {
        buildFromSorted(m.size(), m.entrySet().iterator(), null, null);
    } catch (java.io.IOException cannotHappen) {
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException cannotHappen) {
    }
}
```

So it makes a difference when you create a new `TreeMap` from a `Map` or a `SortedMap` (such as another `TreeMap`). In case of the latter, it will not re-sort.

Answer (score 2):

I have checked Java 8's source code for `TreeMap`, and based on my understandting, it will not re-sort the map when calling the constructor `TreeMap (Map<? extends K, ? extends V>)`.

The constructor calls `putAll (Map<? extends K, ? extends V> map)`, and in this method, if `map` is an instance of `SortedMap`, then the values are added in their current order to the map (via the private method `buildFromSorted (...)`), otherwise each entry is eventually added via the `put (...)` method, which sorts the entries as it is adding them to the map.